# get data about clients in server socket C#

Tags: c#, sockets

I set a socket server in c# and im trying to make a program that will show users in current room, their username, their color, etc...
I want the server to send to the client all the users who connected to room number 2 and has a red color. 
If this code was written in mysql, I would do something like that:

```
SELECT * FROM Clients WHERE Room = '2' AND Color = 'red'
```

but this is a c# code. not SQL. 
any help? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally prefer lambda expressions to query expressions. I would suggest using some like the following:

```
public IEnumerable<User> getUsers(string color, int room)
{
    IEnumerable<User> users = dbContext.Where(x => x.Room == room && x.Color == color);
    return users;
}
```

There are plenty of LINQ tutorials out there.

Comment: @raduflorescu This is an example of a lambda expression. It can be used in any linq query. It does not specifically require entity framework or any other framework. In your answer you referred to linq to sql. This will work with linq to sql or any other feature which supports linq. I find lambda expressions to be simpler than query expressions and more powerful.

Comment: how to create my own method of color? (To be able to to: socket.color = "red";)

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you need:

```
var color = "Red";
var room = "2";
var myQUery= from client in dbContext.Clients 
                      where client.Room = room && client.Color = color
                      select client;
```

You need to follow this tutorial to add linq to sql into your library/project:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384428.aspx

**Edit:**
I've included current solution based on the fact that the author is very familiar with SQL syntax.

Comment: how to create my own method of color?
(To be able to to: socket.color = "red";)